# Choice of generalized eigenvectors, Jordan matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I've some troubles understanding Jordan matrices and generalized eigenvectors, and have a question regarding an exercise. I want to find the Jordan matrix for matrix $A$.

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & -1 & 1 \\
5 & -1 & 4 \\
5 & 1 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Eigenvalues: $$p(\lambda)=(\lambda-3)(\lambda+2)^2$$

Eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_1=3$ is $\vec{v_1}=(0,1,1)$

Eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_2=-2$ is $\vec{v_2}=(-2,2,2)$

From here on the course literature finds generalized eigenvectors from $\vec{v_1}$, to be able to write the Jordan matrix $J=V^{-1}AV$

What is the argument for choosing from $\vec{v_1}$ and not $\vec{v_2}$?
What difference does it make when choosing from which vector we find our generalized eigenvectors from?

Comment: $\lambda_2 = -2$ is an eigenvalue of algebraic multiplicity 2, so we need two vectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $-2$. It would be very strange if your course literature actually finds generalized eigenvectors from $\vec v_1$ rather than from $\vec v_2$.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong. You're correct, the course literature finds generalized eigenvalues for $\vec{v_2}$. I find it hard to structure the information in my head around this, so I asked the professor what the reason was. And he said that it would be impossible to find generalized eigenvalues for $\vec{v_1}$ since it is not in the column space of $(A-\lambda_1 I)$. Is this one of the reason we choose $\vec{v_2}$? Since it's in the column space of $(A-\lambda_2 I)$?